# How to show the Blockly interface using Python metakernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, blockly

I have installed the content from this repository https://github.com/Calysto/metakernel/tree/3d79efe57175336801169a31d148914c8fb4b0d2

The `metakernel/examples/Jigsaw in IPython.ipynb` example should show the Blockly interface withing the output cell. However, when I run the example, the Blockly interface does not show, as in the picture below

[image]

I have tried with different browsers and the results is the same. What is the problem?